# how to clear form after submit in next js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

here I have a contact form and i want all the values of form should be empty after submitting the form.
I have written following code.but this is not working after submitting the values of form remains same.
what is the problem here and how to solve it.

```
export default function contact() {

  const[name,setName]=useState("")
  const[phone,setPhone]=useState("")
  const[email,setEmail]=useState("")
  const[query,setQuery]=useState("")
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

const  handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e);
    let data = {
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      query
    }
    console.log(data);
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/',data).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      setSubmitted(true)
      setName('')
      setPhone('')
      setEmail('')
      setQuery('')
    })
  }
    return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Contact Page</h1>
      </div>
        
        <div >    
           <form action="contact" method="post">
              <input name="name"  onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Name" / ><br />
              <input name="phone" onChange={(e)=>{setPhone(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Phone" /><br />
              <input name="email" onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} type="email" placeholder="E-mail" / ><br />
              <textarea name="text" onChange={(e)=>{setQuery(e.target.value)}} placeholder="How can we help you?" ></textarea><br />
              <button onClick={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e)}} value="Send" >Submit </button>
          </form> 
               
                                
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you are missing `value` prop in your inputs so your inputs are uncontrolled components that's why you are not able to clear them after form submit.

Try to add `value` prop like below:-

```
<input name="name" value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Name" / ><br />
<input name="phone" value={phone} onChange={(e)=>{setPhone(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Phone" /><br />
<input name="email" value={email} onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} type="email" placeholder="E-mail" / ><br />
<textarea name="text" value={query} onChange={(e)=>{setQuery(e.target.value)}} placeholder="How can we help you?" ></textarea><br />
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `value` prop your inputs then your form shall be cleared after submit:

```
<form>
    <input name="name" value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Name" / ><br />
    <input name="phone" value={phone} onChange={(e)=>{setPhone(e.target.value)}} placeholder="Phone" /><br />
    <input name="email" value={email} onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} type="email" placeholder="E-mail" / ><br />
    <textarea name="text" value={query} onChange={(e)=>{setQuery(e.target.value)}} placeholder="How can we help you?" ></textarea><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this is to rest the form using the .reset() method.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("postCodeForm").reset();
```

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that your api-call ends successfully, according your code, you clean form only when request passed successfully :)